# Easier way of doing multiple if statements for the same thing

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Right, so my problem is that I have 18 spinners containing 43 options for a user to select. I want each option to change a link on a different page in order for the user to look at a pdf regarding that option. I have got the shared preferences to work to share the selection and I'm now implementing my if/else if statements but if I do use if/else statements, I will end up with 43 for each spinner and then 43 for each spinner after, ending up me needing to implement over 700 if statements and there has to be an easier way of implementing my idea that I don't know about. Here is a code sample:

```
if (spinnerValue == 1)
    {
        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWeb1);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-1-Communication-and-Employability-Skills-for-IT.pdf'>Unit 1: Communication and Employability Skills for IT</a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }
    else if (spinnerValue == 2){
        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWeb1);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-2-Computer-Systems.pdf'>Unit 2: Computer Systems</a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }
    else if (spinnerValue == 3){
        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWeb1);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-3-Information-Systems.pdf'>Unit 3: Information Systems</a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }
```

So at the end of this, there will be 43 if (spinnervalue == 1 through 43) and 18 spinnervalues. I am very new to java and android studio so any help or guidance perhaps with an explanation with this is much appreciated.

EDIT: My if statements work and a switch would too but I would still need to implement the 43 if/switch statements 18 times. Is there any way that I can do something along the lines of - if (spinnervalue 1 through 18 ==1) - then that would allow me to write the 43 cases once and have it apply to all spinnervalues (1 - 18)

Comment: Use Switch statement

Comment: Actually you can consider using a switch

Comment: I have tried but it looks the similar and will still end up with me needing to implement the 43 cases for 18 spinners.

Comment: Well, since the only thing that's changing is the <a href> value, you can create a method that accepts a string, and depending on the case, you can grab the value from an array

Comment: How about just placing the text lines in an Array/ArrayList? Then you wouldn't need an if or a switch, just select the appropriate string value.

Comment: My if statements work and a switch would too but I would still need to implement the 43 if/switch statements 18 times. Is there any way that I can do something along the lines of - if (spinnervalue 1 through 18 ==1) - then that would allow me to write the 43 cases once and have it apply to all spinnervalues (1 - 18)

Comment: Do it correctly, and use an [array resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray).

Answer (score 2):

Here are my first thoughts on this:

```
String[] fileNames = new String[] {
 //Put your filenames here in order
}
```

And then in your current code:

```
if(spinnerValue<=fileNames.length) { //Make sure the value is valid
    TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWeb1);
    textView.setClickable(true);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    String text = "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/"+fileNames[spinnerValue-1]+".pdf'>"+fileNames[spinnerValue-1].replaceAll("-"," ")+"</a>";
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
}
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way for you, but try to think about how you can set the html dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Since the only difference is the string, and you're using consecutive values 1-43, then easiest would be an array of the texts.

Remember that arrays are zero-based.

```java
private static final String[] SPINNER_TEXTS = {
    /*1*/"<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-1-Communication-and-Employability-Skills-for-IT.pdf'>Unit 1: Communication and Employability Skills for IT</a>",
    /*2*/"<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-2-Computer-Systems.pdf'>Unit 2: Computer Systems</a>",
    /*3*/"<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-3-Information-Systems.pdf'>Unit 3: Information Systems</a>"
};
```

```java
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWeb1);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(SPINNER_TEXTS[spinnerValue - 1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this can be refactored - e.g.

```
    TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWeb1);
    textView.setClickable(true);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    String text = "";
    switch(spinnerValue) {
        case 1:
            text = "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-1-Communication-and-Employability-Skills-for-IT.pdf'>Unit 1: Communication and Employability Skills for IT</a>";
            break;
        case 2:
            text = "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-2-Computer-Systems.pdf'>Unit 2: Computer Systems</a>";
            break;
    }
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

But I'm not convinced that this is the best approach really. I'd probably go with creating a Map (or an Array, given it's just a numerical value for the key) of spinner values -> URLs and use this to populate the links. Would require way less lines of code and be a lot more extendable for the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping table like this:

```
    Map<Integer, String> spinnerValueToLinkMapping = new HashMap<Integer, String> {{
        put(1, "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-1-Communication-and-Employability-Skills-for-IT.pdf'>Unit 1: Communication and Employability Skills for IT</a>");
        put(2, "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-2-Computer-Systems.pdf'>Unit 2: Computer Systems</a>");
        put(3, "<a href='http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/BTEC-Nationals/Information-Technology/2010/Specification/Unit-3-Information-Systems.pdf'>Unit 3: Information Systems</a>");
    }}
```

and then use following code to retrieve needed link:

```
    TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewWeb1);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = spinnerValueToLinkMapping.get(spinnerValue);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Having this, you'll end up with easy to support mapping table and DRY code